# Notes on fourier transform from Terence Tao

Tags: group-theory

Consider the second equation in these [Terence Tao notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/preprints/fourier.pdf);

$f_j(x)= \frac{1}{n} \sum_k f(e^{2\pi i k/n} x) e^{-2\pi i j k/n} $

Is that an application of some theorem in group theory? How could that equation be written in abstract terms, because it seems that a group element is applied to the argument and the inverse is applied to the outside.

Comment: What equation... ?

Comment: Please format your question in a self-contained manner. Leaving the key part of your question to an external source significantly reduces your chances to be answered.

Comment: Okay I wrote the equation, hope that is better.

Comment: I think that $x$ should be interpreted as being $\rho$ in polar representations $\rho e^{i \theta}$.

Comment: I don't think thats whats going on since he is using $z$ for complex numbers.